# gwt load generated class on server side

Tags: java, gwt, reflection

I have custom class generator. in this generator I creating two classes

```
public class WsRpcServerGenerator extends Generator{
   @Override
   public String generate(TreeLogger logger, GeneratorContext context, String typeName) throws UnableToCompleteException {
      JClassType classType;
      try {
         classType = context.getTypeOracle().getType(typeName);
         SourceWriter src;
         try {
            // generating first file xxxAsync for client
            src = generateMethod( classType, context, logger);
            // generating second class for server side
            SourceWriter src2 = generateMethodArgs( classType, context, logger);
         if (src2!=null)
            src2.commit(logger);
         } catch (Exception e) {}
         // returning first class for client
         if (src == null)return typeName + "__AsyncWsRpcGenerated";
            src.commit(logger);         
         return typeName + "__AsyncWsRpcGenerated";
      } catch (NotFoundException e) {}
   }
}
```

I use

```
TestObject obj = GWT.create(TestObject.class);
```

This is work. gwt generated two files. and first is loaded in client.

But I dont know how I can load second file on server side. If I refreshing project in eclipse for visibility generated classes, class is loaded with `test=Class.forName("com.xxx.TestObject__ArgsGenerated");`. but I not wont refreshing project, its library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im found the solution and make own compiler inspirated by original gwt ClassSourceFileComposerFactory

Generator [source](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-ws-rpc/source/browse/trunk/src/com/mostka/rpc/util/)

usage

```
DynamicJavaFileObject composer = new DynamicJavaFileObject("com.xxx","ClassName");

composer.setSuperclass("superclass");
composer.addImport(GWT.class.getCanonicalName());

SourceWriter writer = composer.getSourceWriter();

writer.println("public String test(){return \"test\"}");

writer.commit(logger);
```

Now I can find class on server side

```
Class.forName("com.xxx.ClassName");
```

Answer (score 0):

What Im looking how do it default gwtRpc, gwtRpc save info about rpc serialization policy, what Im saving to class `com.xxx.TestObject__ArgsGenerated`, to plain text file to web directory.
So I must go this way.
in my generator I must create resource file, and put serialization policy there.

```
public class WsRpcServerGenerator extends Generator{
   @Override
   public String generate(TreeLogger logger, GeneratorContext context, String typeName) throws UnableToCompleteException {
      JClassType classType;
      try {
         classType = context.getTypeOracle().getType(typeName);
         SourceWriter src;
         try {
            // generating first file xxxAsync for client
            src = generateMethod( classType, context, logger);
            // generating file to war directorz
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(baos, SerializationPolicyLoader.SERIALIZATION_POLICY_FILE_ENCODING);
            TypeOracle oracle = context.getTypeOracle();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(osw);
            // generate content here
            pw.close();
            byte[] serializationPolicyFileContents = baos.toByteArray();
            String serializationPolicyName = Util.computeStrongName(serializationPolicyFileContents);
            String serializationPolicyFileName = SerializationPolicyLoader.getSerializationPolicyFileName(serializationPolicyName);
            OutputStream os = context.tryCreateResource(logger, serializationPolicyFileName);
            if (os != null) {
                 os.write(serializationPolicyFileContents);
                 GeneratedResource resource = ctx.commitResource(logger, os);
            }    
         // returning first class for client
         if (src == null)return typeName + "__AsyncWsRpcGenerated";
            src.commit(logger);         
         return typeName + "__AsyncWsRpcGenerated";
      } catch (NotFoundException e | IOException e) {}
   }
}
```

reading policy on server side

```
HttpServlet servlet;
String modulename; // sended from client GWT.getModuleBaseURL() reolacing host
Sending serialiyationpolicyid; // from generated xxxAsync
// Open the RPC resource file and read its contents.
InputStream is=servlet.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(modulename+"/"+serialiyationpolicyid+".rpc");
// read policy
```